# JSLINT Error MSG with JSON.parse()

Tags: json, jslint

using JSLINT on this simple example of receiving JSON via Assignment(without eval()), although simple, I'm concered with doing this correctly before tackling larger task:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29#quickIDX6

```
var JSONFile = "someVar = {\"color\":\"blue\"}";

var myParse = JSON.parse(JSONFile);
alert(JSONFile);
```

**The error returned is:**

> ```
> Error:
> Problem at line 5 character 1: 'alert' was used before it was defined.   
> alert(JSONFile);
> ```

**Tried on: 08/25/11**

```
var JSONFile = "someVar = {\"color\":\"blue\"}";

var myParse = JSON.parse(JSONFile);
/*global alert */alert(JSONFile);
```

**Returned From Scratchpad:**

> [06:27:25.349] JSON.parse: unexpected character @Scratchpad:4  @
>   Scratchpad:4

Comment: [06:27:25.349] JSON.parse: unexpected character
@Scratchpad:4

Answer (score 4):

This seems like it has pretty good explanation: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

I am reading through it now since I am new to javascript (and therefore jslint as well), and I am finding it useful.

This is what I found on some other site that seemed to work for me: Prefix your alert with `/*global alert */` That should work. I think this has something to do with alert having some special meaning in JSLINT